# Avoid HttpWebRequest autoredirection

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have an application which sends HttpWebRequest to the server and handles the responses. I have to use AllowAutoRedirect property to false in order for disabling auto redirect.

Can we achive the same functionaliy without making any code change by doing any setting in registry or IE.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the request should follow redirection responses.

```
public virtual bool AllowAutoRedirect { get; set; }
```

true if the request should automatically follow redirection responses from the Internet resource; otherwise, false. The default value is true.  If AllowAutoRedirect is set to false, all responses with an HTTP status code from 300 to 399 is returned to the application.